# How to call a hook from an exported function since it is not inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, service, components

I cannot access my service class methods when I convert the export to service rather than methods:

```
const HttpService = () => {
  
  const AUTH_TOKEN = localStorage.getItem("tokenKey");
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const postWithoutAuth = (url, body) => {
    const request = axios.post(url, body);
    return request.then((response) => response.data);
  };
};

export default HttpService;
```

I am trying to access the `postWithoutAuth` method as shown below:

```
import { HttpService } from "../../services/HttpService";
// I think I should use like this:
import HttpService from "../../services/HttpService";

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    HttpService.postWithoutAuth("/auth/signup", formValues)
      .then((response) => {})
      .catch((error) => {});
  };
```

So, is it a proper way to call this service method?

Comment: No, it isn't. Why is `HttpService` a function?

Comment: `const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't make `HttpService` a function but just a file in which you include all the functions you want to export :

```js
export const postWithoutAuth = (url, body) => {
  const request = axios.post(url, body);
  return request.then((response) => response.data);
};
export const anotherOne= (url, body) => {
  //...
};
```

Now you can import from it :

```js
import { postWithoutAuth, anotherOne } from "../../services/HttpService";
```

**Update to reply to the op question update:**

If you want to use a hook from the `postWithoutAuth` function then you pass a function to it from the parent component that uses the hook because

> hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

```js
export const postWithoutAuth = (url, body, functionHook) => {
  const request = axios.post(url, body);
  return request.then((response) => {
     response.data;
     functionHook();
  });
};
```

from the parent component :

```js
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import { postWithoutAuth } from "../../services/HttpService";

const Parent = () => {
  
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const functionHook = () => {
    enqueueSnackbar("Failed to Login", {
      variant: "error",
    });
  };
}

<div>
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      postWithoutAuth(url, body, functionHook);
    }}
  >
    Click me
  </button>
</div>;
```

You can make multiple functions similar to the `functionHook` in your parent component that display different alerts and you can also pass more then one function the the `postWithoutAuth` function and based on the `responde.data` you know what function to execute

Comment: Yes, but I want to use `const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();` in the service. then, how could I use it if I export each method?

Comment: I juste updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. But, in that case I would need to implement the logic out of service methods that I don't want. So, I decided to use logic in the methods that are calling service methods

Comment: you don't implement the logic out of service methods but inside it and then you decide which function to execute thats all . for example you pass 2 functions,  the first functionHookOk which show an OK alert and another function functionHookFalse that shows a FALSE alert then you check the response.data in the service if its ok you execute functionHookOk else you execute functionHookFalse

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to access a function declared inside another function that is not returned in some way.

`HttpService` does not look like it should be a function at all. Instead, you can directly export the `postWithoutAuth` function.

```js
export const postWithoutAuth = (url, body) => {
    const request = axios.post(url, body);
    return request.then((response) => response.data);
};
```

Then, you can use it in another file like so:

```js
import { postWithoutAuth } from "../../services/HttpService";
```

Comment: Actually, it was exactly as you mentioned. But, but I need to use const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar(); in the service. then, how could I use it if I export each method? –

Comment: And could you also explain a little bit when I need to create as a function and when not?

Comment: @hexadecimal If you're trying to define a hook called `useSnackbar`, just create a function with that name that returns an object with the `enqueueSnackbar` property.

Comment: Then, how could I merge it with the service and method call? Could you post an example pls?

Comment: @hexadecimal Something like this should work: https://pastebin.com/FADbhmKz

Comment: Actually I could not understand, because you do not indicated how can I use enqueueSnackbar in the service method. Any example pls?

Comment: @hexadecimal I don't understand what you mean. After `const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();` in your component, you can directly call `enqueueSnackbar`. There is nothing special about it; it's just like any other function.

Comment: Where should I create that in the service class?

Comment: And each service method, I will make different things using `useSnackbar()`. So, why don't you post an example including service methods?

Comment: Normally I call `useSnackbar()` in the components that calls service method. But, instead of repeating the same code in the components, I just wanted to move this logic to the service method.